# How to collate the two javascript arrays produced by the vuetify options.sortBy and sortDesc for pushing to mongodb aggregate pipeline?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vuetify.js, aggregate, reduce

Given the two javascript arrays produced by the vuetify table options.sortBy and sortDesc:

```
options.sortBy = ['name', 'email'];  // fields to sort
options.sortDesc = [ false, true ];  // whether to sort field descending
```

Desired result:

```
sort = { $sort: { name: -1, email: 1 } };
```

So that we can push into mongodb aggregate pipeline array like:

```
pipeline.push(sort);
```

Code available in [this branch](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-web/tree/server-side-pagination).

Answer (score 0):

It ends up being a good case for `reduce`.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
type SortValue = 'asc' | 'desc' | 'ascending' | 'descending' | 1 | -1;

let sort:{[key:string]:SortValue} =
  query.sortBy === undefined ||
  query.sortDesc === undefined ? undefined :
  query.sortBy.split(',').reduce((sort:{[key:string]:SortValue}, field:SortValue, index:number) => {
    const sortDesc = query.sortDesc.split(',')[index];
    const sortValue = !!(parseInt(sortDesc) || sortDesc === "true") ? 1 : -1;
    sort[field] = sortValue;
    return sort;
  }, {});

pagination.sort = sort;
```

Open to improvements/variants. Thanks!

Code available in [this branch](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-web/tree/server-side-pagination).